# How to get max number from an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, max

I already know about JavaScript's `Math.max(13, 24, n)` which returns the max number from the arguments passed but what I want to know is how to get a max number from a JavaScript array like: `Math.max( [23, 482, 84, 0, 3] )` where `Math.max` doesn't works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `.apply()` function to essentially "split" the array into separate arguments.

```
Math.max.apply(Math, some_array);
```

Or, in ES6:

```
Math.max(...some_array);
```